# How do I route Domains to my Dedicated Server in order to use e-mail

Tags: email, dns

I think what I need is some general explanation as to how this works, but here is my problem.

I have a dedicated server with 1&1, everything is working perfect, I have several clients' websites on the dedicated server all running through different domains that I have purchased through 1&1.

The server is running ZPanel (Not for long, so please spare me the "risky choice" speech), and I have setup some mailboxes that RECEIVE e-mail perfectly!!! When it comes to sending e-mail, it doesn't for some recipients, and for others it goes straight to SPAM/JUNK.

What could be happening here? I understand it is a vague question, I can only assume the domain DNS settings are correct otherwise e-mails wouldn't be received at all right? Is this a mail server problem?

The dedicated server is running Linux 12.04-ish.

Any questions to help I am more than pleased to answer.

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure a PTR and SPF record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer.

It turns out my Dedicated Server IP address was blacklisted which made Hotmail throw a hissy fit. Here is a tool you can use to check if your IP has been blacklisted: http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/

It turns out, to be more specific about this issue, that I was using ZPanel which pretty much automatically blacklists IPs running ZPanel due to the obvious security flaws.

Thanks very much for the original answer and it did help me eventually track this problem down.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, in order to avoid being flagged as spammer you will need a pointer record `PTR`  mapping your domain to your ip address and a `SPF` record.

**How it works:**

Spam filters will check if your ip address belongs to the domain you're claiming it does. So it will do a reverse DNS lookup and if you don't have a `PTR` record it will flag the email as possible spam.

In addition to reverse dns lookup, some spam filters will also check the `SPF` Sender Policy Framework rules, if your ip address is not included in that rule it will flag the email as possible spam.

Take a look at rackspace email server:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp/test$ dig mx1.emailsrvr.com +short
108.166.43.1
```

Reverse DNS:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp/test$ dig -x 108.166.43.1 +short
mx1.emailsrvr.com.
```

SPF:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp/test$ dig txt emailsrvr.com +short
"v=spf1 ip4:67.192.241.0/24 ip4:98.129.184.0/23 ip4:173.203.2.0/25 ip4:173.203.6.0/23 ip4:50.57.0.0/27 ip4:108.166.43.0/24 ip4:173.203.187.0/25 ip4:204.232.172.40 ~all"
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#PTR

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework